Testing Create Action -> undefined method `post' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::
Trying to test my controllers and I keep getting a errors pertaining to the create action. It's a fresh rails project and it is api only. Been at it for two days going through stackoverflow, but unfortunately none of the solutions out there for problems that closely resembled my issue worked.
NoMethodError: undefined method `post' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::SignupController::POSTCreate "creates a new user" (./spec/controllers/signup_controller_spec.rb:17)>

My Routes
post 'signup', controller: :signup, action: :create

My Controller:
# frozen_string_literal: true

class SignupController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      payload = { user_id: user.id }
      session = JWTSessions::Session.new(payload: payload, refresh_by_access_allowed: true)
      tokens = session.login

      response.set_cookie(JWTSessions.access_cookie,
                          value: tokens[:access],
                          httponly: true,
                          secure: Rails.env.production?)
      render json: { csrf: tokens[:csrf] }
    else
      render json: { error: user.errors.full_messages.join(' ') }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end

My corresponding spec file
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SignupController, type: :controller do

  describe 'POST #create' do
    let(:user_params) { { email: 'test@email.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password' } }

    it 'returns http success' do
      post :create, params: user_params
      expect(response).to be_successful
      expect(response_json.keys).to eq ['csrf']
      expect(response.cookies[JWTSessions.access_cookie]).to be_present
    end

    it 'creates a new user' do
      expect {
        post :create, params: user_params
      }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end

My spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ResponseHelper
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|

    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end

My rails_helper.rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'
require 'rspec-rails'
require 'database_cleaner'

begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  abort e.to_s.strip
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end  
  
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end 
  
  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end  
  
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end  
  
  config.before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end  
  
  config.after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end

My Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "3.2.2"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.8.1"

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", ">= 5.0"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
# gem "jbuilder"

gem "redis", ">= 4.0.1"
gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"
gem "jwt_sessions", "~> 3.2", ">= 3.2.2"
gem "rack-cors", "~> 2.0", ">= 2.0.2" 

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ windows jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", "~> 1.18", ">= 1.18.3", require: false

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "pry-byebug", "~> 3.10", ">= 3.10.1" 
  gem "pry-rails", "~> 0.3.9"
  gem "rails-controller-testing", "~> 1.0.5"
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 6.1", ">= 6.1.2"
  gem "factory_bot_rails", "~> 6.4", ">= 6.4.3"
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 2.0", ">= 2.0.2"
  gem "capybara", "~> 3.40"
end

group :development do
  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  gem "spring"
  gem "listen", "~> 3.0.5"
  gem "spring-watcher-listen", "~> 2.0.0"
end




I don't know why that's not working. Your code looks perfectly fine to me. If I were to take a wild guess, I'd say that you haven't actually saved the file / are actually not testing the thing you think. Try adding a raise("TEST") in the spec, to see if it fails with that message.
